# Patched up my tire and still lost air again

Tags: tire, innertube, fixed-gear

I recently popped my tube and I took it out and put a patch on it and made sure that there were no other holes and I didn't find any so I filled it up and rode on it for about an hour, then the next day it was flat. Can you guys please help me!?

And I also patched up the hole in the tire so if anyone can help me that would great.

Comment: Inspect the tire and make sure there is nothing left in there from when it punctured. Sometimes whatever punctured the tube last time (could be glass, thorns, rocks, etc.) can stay stuck in the tire causing another section of the tube to go.

Additionally, if the hole is too big, it may be better to just put in a new tube rather than patching it.

Comment: You may not have patched it properly as well.

Comment: First off, if indeed the tire actually "popped" that means there was a substantial hole in both tube and tire.  In such a situation both tube and tire need to be replaced.  If the tire simply went flat rapidly, however, then your repair technique is defective or there is something causing new punctures.

Answer (score 0):

As well as checking for debris in the tyres, applying the patch properly etc., you need to be careful not to give yourself a "[pinch flat](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16480/what-are-pinch-flats)" when you put the tyre back on the rim. This is caused when you trap the tube between the tyre and the rim, putting a fresh hole in your recently repaired tube.

Answer (score 0):

Patched up the hole in the tire?  How did you do that?  You can test the patched inner tube by leaving it out and inflated over night, but if you have a tear in the tire, there's reasons it can't be patched.  Let us know how you pulled it off if you can manage to make patching a torn tire work.

Answer (score -1):

Using the scraping tool or sandpaper to abrade the patch area may also leave the tube thinner. When inflated the thinner area stretches and may allow air to leak. You might have to stick the (temporarily) inflated tube under water to find these tiny leaks. Scrape sparingly, and the tube may still have plenty of life left. I am still riding a tube with six patches spread around on it.

Also, using a CO2 inflator always seems to leave the tube flat about a day later. If you use one of those to inflate a tube on the road, expect to re-inflate later with a proper pump.

Comment: I'm not convinced that sanding a tiny amount of rubber off a tube will affect the percolation rate so much that the tyre will go down faster. If you can find research I'd love to see it, but otherwise it sounds silly.

Comment: Unless the tube is exceptionally thin (as are a very few "high performance" racing types), the amount scraping/sanding needed to prep the tube for a patch should have no effect on the tube's ability to hold air.